# How to detect if a port is already in use in C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm writing a simple web server. I'd like to let the user set the port the server listen to,
but how could I know if the port the user input is already in use or not?(if I know it's already in use, I can tell them to input another one.)

Answer (score 10):

Simply try to `bind` to the port and if it fails check for `EADDRINUSE` in `errno`. This is the only way, since to be correct any such check must be atomic. If you did a separate check then tried to bind to the port after finding that it was not in use, another process could bind to the port in the intervening time, again causing it to fail. Similarly, if you did a separate check and found the port already in use, the process that was using it could close the port, exit, or crash in the intervening time, again making the result incorrect.

The point of all this (the reason I wrote a long answer rather than a short answer) is that the correct, robust way to check "Can I do such-and-such?" is almost always to *try to do it* and check for failure. Any other approach can lead to race conditions, and in many cases race conditions (although probably not yours) race conditions are security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 5):

`bind()` will fail:

> On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
>
> EADDRINUSE
> The given address is already in use.

Comment: But in this way I have to create a server socket...bind()...then close it..Is there a simpler way?

Comment: No, that's the only proper way. Why do you want to close it anyway? Simply use it for listening if you already bound it - you cannot know if it'll still be available later as another process could have bound to that port in the meantime.

Comment: @wong2: Read my answer. There's no way to determine the answer to your question ("Is the port already in use?") without possibly getting it wrong unless you bind the port and keep it bound until you're ready to use it. Checking in advance (and then freeing it) is subject to giving wrong answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Try to connect to that port on `localhost`.

Comment: Add some of the reasons it's a bad idea and ways this test could fail, and your answer might be worthwhile...

Comment: a) the running server may listen a particular interface, and the connection to `localhost` won't check it; b) timeouts; c) I used this method to check the port to start a TCP server as a separate process (it didn't return proper error codes on failures, so that was the only way to check it).

Comment: By the way, (a) is a problem even if you atomically test by binding the port. Even if you succeed getting a connection on 0.0.0.0:port, some other process might have already bound aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:port (the ip of the external network address).

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko, it answers the question about how check if the port is busy, why it should be in comments?

Comment: I can totally see why Wong doesn't want to bind() - if you're doing monitoring and a periodic check, you don't want to risk accidentally grabbing a port while a process is restarting.

Answer (score 0):

if bind() shows some error

Answer (score 0):

Just create a socket and call bind(). If bind() success, then proceed to listen(), otherwise you should perform some error handling procedure, such as switch to a default port, print error message and wait for user interact, or at least log and quit.